# Problema na execução da tarefa com Gulp & SASS?

Tags: sass, gulp, gulpjs

Estou criando uma tarefa que compila, renomeia e simplifica os arquivos `.scss` para `.css`. Minha estrutura de arquivos está assim:

```
assets/
|__ css/
|__ sass/
|   |__ uma-pasta/
|   |   |__ alguns.scss
|   |   |__ arquivos.scss
|   |   |__ vão.scss
|   |   |__ aqui.scss
|   |__ outra-pasta/
|       |__ alguns.scss
|       |__ outros.scss
|       |__ arquivos.scss
|       |__ vão.scss
|       |__ aqui.scss
|__ _variables.scss
```

Porém quando eu executo a seguinte task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src(['!assets/sass/outra-pasta/**/*.scss', 'assets/sass/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH + 'assets/css'))
});
```

As variáveis localizadas no `assets/sass/_variables.scss` não são concatenadas com os outros arquivos, e então eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    assets/sass/uma-pasta/arquivos.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$variable".
    on line 3 of stdin
>>  width: $variable;
--------^
```

E o arquivo `assets/sass/_variables.scss` está dessa maneira:

```
$variable: 20px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Confesso que nunca usei `gulp`, mas se a lógica for a mesma do `grunt`, acredito que você deva começar por inserir o arquivo de variáveis antes de inserir os demais arquivos. Tente o seguinte:

```
gulp.src([
    'assets/sass/variables.scss', 
    'assets/sass/**/*.scss'
])
```

Caso você tenha outros arquivos ainda na pasta raiz, basta usar algo assim:

```
gulp.src([
    'assets/sass/variables.scss', 
    'assets/sass/*.scss', 
    'assets/sass/**/*.scss'
])
```

Assim as variáveis irão existir para todos os arquivos.

---

Editado:

Outra observação, não sei se foi erro seu na hora de passar a questão para o SO ou se realmente é o erro. Mas o log diz que não encontrou a variável `$minhavariavel` e o nome que você deu em seguida foi: `$variable`. Certifique-se de não haver nenhum erro de syntax com os nomes das variáveis.

Comment: Então na realidade não funcionou :/ Não tenho ideia de como posso fazer isso de uma maneira inteligente. E realmente aquele erro das variáveis foi minha culpa, me confundi na edição da pergunta mas já arrumei. De qualquer maneira muito obrigado!

Comment: Mas o que ele apresenta de erro agora? A mesma coisa?

Comment: Sim! Ele continua apresentando o mesmo erro :/

Comment: A solução que consegui encontrar foi dar `@include` das variáveis dentro de cada arquivo `.scss`. Pois pelo que eu andei vendo por ai, o módulo do *gulp-sass* interpreta cada arquivo individualmente, ou seja ele compila as variáveis porém ele fica no escopo do arquivo tornando elas NÃO-GLOBAIS, e assim não tenho acesso em outros arquivos.

Comment: No grunt eu sei que existe essa função, mas é através de um módulo. Mas mesmo assim, a lógica de incluir primeiro as variáveis está valendo, mesmo com o @include =D

Comment: Pois é... O único problema ao meu ver agora, é que se a sua maneira tivesse funcionado, eu teria que escrever uma vez só o caminho para as variáveis e pronto! Desse jeito eu preciso sempre estar importando elas dentro do arquivo.